# Regex to match and optionally remove a / at the end of an url

Tags: regex

I have a form should get urls in the following formats:

```
http://website.com/test/1

http://website.com/test/1/
```

My regex is currently this:

```
url.match(/website.com(.*)/);
```

I want the capture group to match the content and automatically remove the last "/" at the end of the URL, so that, no matter if there is / or not, it would always return "/test/1" . How?

Comment: Try `url.match(/website\.com(.*?)\/?$/);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below regex,

`url.match(/website.com(.*)\b/);`

it should work for your case. Let me know if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Regexs' can't really "remove"/[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) characters. Say, for example, you have a field where you can enter a URL. You can restrict the user from adding a "/", like either giving him an error message that says: "Remove the / in the end of your URL" or just not allow it (with Javascript, so when they try to add it, the "/" gets removed).

I'll give you a regex expression that will check for everything in your URL:

```
(https?:\/\/)?(([A-Za-z0-9]+)((\.[a-z]{1,3})))(\/\w+)\/(\d)\/?
```

Here's what this regex expression does:

First it checks to see if http:// or https:// is present in the URL: `(https?:\/\/)?`
The `https?` basically means: if http has an "s" at the end of it,  hence the `s?` (which could be any character, though: `a? b? c? 1? 2? 3?`). It's the same with the "?" after `(https?:\/\/)`: `(https?:\/\/)?`, but here it checks for, as said, if the entire http:// or https:// is present. Meaning that an URL like this: example.com (without the http or https in the beginning) would get matched too.

Then we have this entire section of the expression: `(([A-Za-z0-9]+)((\.[a-z]{1,3})))`. Let's break it down a bit:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

Here it checks for any letters or numbers (example: "website"), (uppercase or lowercase) until it meets: `((\.[a-z]{1,3}))`, which checks any letters any lowercase only with a maximum of 3 letters (example: .com).

So `(([A-Za-z0-9]+)((\.[a-z]{1,3})))` would match, just to mention a few examples: stackoverflow.com, twitter.com, google.se but not example.online, because of the `{1,3}` which basically says "between 1 to 3" letters only.

Then we have the last part: `(\/\w+)\/(\d)\/?`. First we have `(\/\w+)` which checks for any word following a slash, for example: "/test". The `\w` basically mean check for any word.

After that it check for a "/": `\/`, and lastly a number `(\d)`, following the "/", so for example: "/1". In the end of this regex expression we have a `\/?`, which just checks to see if there is a trailing slash or not.

So in PHP this regex expression could be used like this:

```
$pattern = "/(https?:\/\/)?(([A-Za-z0-9]+)((\.[a-z]{1,3})))(\/\w+)\/(\d)\/?/";
$url = "https://example.com/user/1/";

if(preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches)){
echo $matches[1]; // Will echo https://
echo $matches[2]; // Will echo "example.com"
echo $matches[3]; // Will echo "example"
echo $matches[4]; // Will echo ".com"
echo $matches[5]; // Will echo ".com"
echo $matches[6]; // Will echo "/user"
echo $matches[7]; // Will echo "1"

var_dump($matches); // Will dump the array
}
```

Hope this helps.

Edit; Of course, the regex can be written in more ways and it's differently for different languages. But this is just an example of how I usually build my regexs'; I always structure it and break it down into parts so I can more easily see what is what and try to think of everything I want to check for in a regex.